# Why does reloading a widget at midnight fail?

Tags: swift, widgetkit

I have a WidgetKit widget that generates a timeline with 47 entries, spaced at half hour intervals, with a reload policy set to half an hour after the last entry.  The effect is the reload should happen just after midnight every day.

The initial load works fine and the widget updates every half an hour through the day.  With the debugger attached the reload occurs as expected just after midnight and the widget continues updating.  But in TestFlight and app store releases the widget never reloads after midnight.

When I look at the system logs I can see the OS is trying to reload the timeline every few hours after the last entry, but is failing with this error:

```
Subsystem: com.apple.chrono
Category: timeline.store
[my.bundle.id:my.widget.kind:systemMedium::321.00/148.00/20.20:(null)] reload: failed with error Couldn’t communicate with a helper application.)
```

I've added logging to the first line of `getTimeline(in:completion:)`, so I can see it isn't being called when the problem occurs.

How can I make my timeline reload after the last entry please?

Tapping on the widget to open the app, interacting with the app and then putting it in the background causes the widget to reload successfully, even though the app isn't calling `reloadAllTimelines()`.

The reload happens successfully when the debugger is attached.

Any help would be massively appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Please add the code you use to reload the timeline.

Comment: Does the widget reloading work if you install a release build of your app on your device without going through the AppStore/TestFlight? It is possible that your release/debug configs have a difference that's causing the issue. However, without a [mcve], it's impossible to know for sure.

Comment: `Couldn’t communicate with a helper application` usually means something has crashed and an IPC/XPC connection was dropped. So connect your device, open Xcode's "Devices and Simulators" dialog and view the device logs: are there any crash logs from your widget or intent handler?

Comment: @DarkDust: there are no crashes from the widget or the app.  The widget isn't configurable, so there's no intent handler.

Comment: @burnsi `completion(Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .after(reloadDate)))`, where `reloadDate` is just after midnight.

Comment: I meant the code you use to aquire the data for a new timeline.